# Problem setting up elm with react-elm-components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, elm

I'm trying to run a basic react project with elm, and for this I am using [react-elm-components](https://github.com/akselw/react-elm-components). I've created the project with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). I've configurated the webpack directly from the node modules, you can check it [here](https://gist.github.com/wellyal/5d378132b8859ba797ece9926b96406a). But it's not working, I'm struggling with this error message:

> ./src/components/elm/Test.elm Error: Compiler process exited with
>   error Compilation failed
>   -- NO elm.json FILE ------------------------------------------------------------
>
> It looks like you are starting a new Elm project. Very exciting! Try
>   running:
>
> ```
> elm init
> ```
>
> It will help you get set up. It is really simple!

This command doesn't even exist for me. My project structure is basically like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the example you started from was targeting Elm 0.18. A lot of things have changed in Elm 0.19 ([changelog](https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.19.md)), including the package file (which was changed from `elm-package.json` to just `elm.json`)

If you are just trying out Elm, perhaps you'd be better off installing Elm 0.18 for now just to get the project up and running.

Sidenote - And if you manage to upgrade the projects to Elm 0.19, I'm sure the project maintainers would appreciate a pull request!

Comment: I don't understand. The version I'm using on elm-package.json file its lower than 0.19, isn't it?

Comment: I'm guessing the version of the Elm compiler on your system is 0.19. Try running `elm --version` from the terminal so see what version you're running

Comment: yep the version is 0.18.0

Comment: Hmmm... the `elm.json` file format was only introduced in 0.19. Could you be running in an editor that's referencing a different elm version?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm still trying to figure out. If I have anything new I'll let you know.

Comment: Maybe the elm-webpack-loader is trying to build on the latest version of elm.